# Connecting Android directly to sql server over local host without using web serices

Tags: android, sql-server-2005

i want to develop a android application that can work only on the android emulator of my desktop , i have no idea of web service ,is there any way i can connect android directly to database just like we connect in ASp.net?

Comment: Maybe you should be looking at eLance for some assistance ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672012/class-not-found-although-particular-jar-is-added-in-project-connect-to-sqlserve?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Android includes a full implementation of sqlite.  Vogella has a nice tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

If you're truly wanting to accomplish this as a locally hosted web service you're going to have to include apache (or similar) in some way.  Infinitely harder than just creating a local database.

Comment: yah exactly i want to use locally database-SQL server , can you tell me how to begin?

Answer (score 0):

Be clear on what exactly you need?

For stand alone android application you can use SQlite database provided by android

[SQllite tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

If you are looking to create a webservice... you can try the below link

[WebService example](http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/webservicecallfromandroid/)

Comment: Sir, i need to connect an android app to a sql server database and have no idea about web service , so i will prefer if you can tell me an alternate.

Comment: download the required library and add it to your project properties..Ex MySql connector 5.1.2 and do jdbc connection

Answer (score 0):

How about running Android in a virtual machine on a server:
http://androvm.org/blog/
(uses VirtualBox which can run on Windows.)

Then connect via local host to SQL server running on same Windows server.

edit: Running Android in virtual box is like running it on an emulator, but much faster and greater functionality, e.g. the ability to communicate with the host machine via a variety of techniques including via virtual network adapter.

Comment: and how to connect it to sql server

Comment: via the virtual network interface - as if they were running on different machines.