# How to get data from SQL database through internet

Tags: android, database, windows, sql-server-2005

I have SQL database on PC with Windows. I have to create android application that will get data from that database through internet. I don't know how to do it. Can anybody give me advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your using SQL Server? There are Few Steps that we need to be followed if we are connecting Android to a SQLServer

Please checkout the answer in this link

[Class not found although particular jar is added in project (android to sqlserver without webservice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672012/class-not-found-although-particular-jar-is-added-in-project-android-to-sqlserve?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thank you for your anser. I don't reale know is there SQLServer. I know only that there is Windows application on PC that has access to SQL database. And programmer that created this app sad that i can have direct access to database. But would be better to use some web service or application service. Sory for my bad English.

Comment: Please confirm which database they are using. The method of connectivity depends upon the database that they are using. The above method is for connecting to SQL Server Database.

Comment: They are using MS SQL server 2005

Comment: I think they might have already enabled remote access to the SQL Server 2005. If so, you only need the Database Server IP Address, Instance Name, Database Name, Port Number, User Name and Password to connect to that database. You can use the same source code (Step 9 in the link) shown in the link and replace the above mentioned details.